# Trying to design form to query and edit records Access

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I'm trying to make an Access database where we can scan in a list of bar-codes, batch edit information for them, then save all the records. Later, they will need to be scanned again to batch edit more information such as shipping and order numbers.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to best design this? To start with, I've (1) made separate tables for "orders" and "parts" and (2) created a form of text boxes and a button attempting to apply this info to a part subform where records are created via the bar-code scanner. I'm a rather new Access designer. Thanks!

The questions are:

1. I'm not sure how to query these records via the bar code (Part_ID field) to apply order information to them later.
2. I can't currently update all new part records at once through my form.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little guide on how to do it. Let me know if you have any questions.

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim Rs As DAO.Recordset

'Here is an example of a vba qarry in access. tblOrdersWhere is obviously your table.
'orderNum is a column name in your table pref a primary key
'txtOrderNum.Value is the value of a text box
'If you want just a simple select * from table you can put after db.OpenRecordset("tblOrders")

set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from tblOrders Where orderNum like '*" & txtOrderNum.Value & "*';", dbOpenDynaset) 


'This is how you update records in Access
'If you want to update it's Rs.Edit instead of Rs.AddNew

   Rs.AddNew
   Rs("OrderItem").Value = txtGroupName.Value
   Rs("OrderTime").Value = txtGroupNum.Value
   rs.Update
```

Comment: Thanks! When I try your simple select statement, I'm getting error 91 (object variable not set), and when I try the long one, I get 424, object required. Any ideas? 

Should I run this code in the parent form with the text boxes or the subform? I'm trying the subform mostly with a button by each record, but also a main button on the parent form.